# on small screens bootsrap menu overlaps content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and am trying to figure out why my menu on the a smaller screen overlaps my picture instead of pushing it down. 
I want to have a fixed menu on all screen sizes and it is fine on the desktop sizes, and is actually fixed on 768px. But it needs to push the content down vertically on smaller sizes and right now it is going over the top of my picture.
I have seen the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583061/bootstrap-navbar-header-overlaps-content-on-small-screens) that said to change to a static header, which I tried, but lost the fixed header in the desktop and still did not push the picture down when expanding the menu on a smaller screen. Something must be off with my basic structure perhaps, as opposed to my css, as I have not really styled the small sized screens yet with css since it seems like a different type of problem. I want to keep the fixed header at all times, and push content down on smaller sizes using the sandwich menu, in what I would think is a more normal process.
Bootstrap is v3.3.7
Any insight would be greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/head-wrapper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/navbar1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/first-picture.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="top-header"><div class="top-header">
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div class="telephone-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span></div>
    <div class="tele-number"><a href="tel:+15302731343" target="new">530-273-1343</a></div>
    <div class="email-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
    <div class="email-address"><a href="mailto:churchoffice@cbc.org">Email CBC</a></div>
  </div>
</div></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
</div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="#">I'm New</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Beliefs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ministries</a></li>
          <div class="menu-picture"><span class="navbar-brand" href="#"><a href="http://www.gvcbc.org" target="_self"><img src="images/GBCBC-LOGO2.jpg" alt="My Logo"></a></span></div>
          <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sermons</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News/Events</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<div class="container-fluid test">
  <div class="first-picture"><img src="images/sermon.jpg" width="960" height="600" alt=""/></div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you fix an element - it removes that element from the dom and is therefore out of the flow of the content. You will need to add either padding or a margin to the body - to offset the height of the fixed navbar.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I had seen that idea in another post, but it still didn't affect my drop down menu in the collapsed mode when I added 70 or 100 px, and did not push the picture down.  And I do still see the .navbar.mavbar-default.navbar-fixed-top in my dom panel. I may be misunderstanding a bit.